# Find the reversed word in an array of words

Tags: javascript, arrays, reverse, indexof

I need to write a function that takes an `array` of a particular word and finds the index of the reversed version.

Ex. I need to return the index of 'peehs'

```
var example = ['sheep', 'sheep', 'sheep', 'peehs', 'sheep'];
var result = 3
```

Just to clarify, the function already receives an Array and it's not specific to the example mentioned above. So I could recieve an Array such as;

```
var example = ['horse', 'esroh', 'horse', 'horse']
var result = 1
```

Also, as some commentors have suggested, I don't know the given array. Therefore I need to find the word that occurs more than once, to then find the index of the word that occurs only once.

I originally thought I could take the first index of the array and compare it to the rest, however the first index could be the reversed version so that wouldn't work.

Comment: "(e.g. the given string is ['sheep', 'sheep', 'sheep', 'peehs', 'sheep'] I need to return the index of 'peehs') in this example it should return 3." -> `indexOf` returns exactly that. What do you need "reversed"?

Comment: No as in I revieve a string like the example above. I need to write a function that identifies the index of the reversed version.

Comment: You already have it, it's `indexOf`. Your problem is to regocnize the the reversed version.

Comment: [How do I ask and answer homework questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you absolutely have to use .split, .join, and .reverse for this? From your explanation I'm not sure it makes sense to use them.

This would be my solution, based on the assumption that the reversed word only appears once, the normal word appears more than once, that those are the only strings in the array, and you don't know what the word is beforehand:

```
let wordArr = ['sheep', 'sheep', 'sheep', 'peehs', 'sheep'];
let tempArr = wordArr.slice().sort();
if(tempArr [0] !== tempArr [1]) {
    console.log(wordArr.indexOf(tempArr[0]));
} else {
    console.log(wordArr.indexOf(tempArr[tempArr.length -1]));
}
```

Presumably you can't just do .indexOf('peehs') as one commentator has suggested. This solution has to dynamically find what the word used in the array is, and find the reversed word which is the odd one out.

Comment: That's the exact question I was asking thanks. I don't know what the given word is, so I need to find a word that occurs more than once, then find the index of the word that doesn't occur more than once.

Comment: Great, if that answers your original question then you can accept this as the official answer & upvote it. If there's still issues then point them out and I can try and solve them.

Comment: Cheers, such a simple solution, was thinking far too into it!

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example implementation:

```js
var strings = ['sheep', 'sheep', 'sheep', 'peehs', 'sheep'];
var searchString = 'sheep';

function reverseString(str) {
  return str.split('').reverse().join('');
}

function indexOfReverseString(str, arr) {
  return arr.indexOf(reverseString(str));
}

console.log(indexOfReverseString(searchString, strings));
```

#### Explanation

- Use `split('')`, `reverse()` and `join('')` to convert to an array of characters, then reverse it and convert back to string.
- Use `indexOf` to find the index of the reverse string in the array (`-1` if there are no matches).

Comment: I think the meat of OP question is finding `searchString`.

Comment: You mean the reverse of `searchString`, @Solo.

Comment: Yes, but you need to know which is non-reversed version first.

Answer (score 0):

Follow these steps:

1. Take Input from console or whatever source you have
   input <-String
2. trim the string for `[` and `]`
3. Split if for `,`, you will get an array
4. Now, you have to be exact about where your string is i.e. position
5. reverse the string
   reversedstring<- `String.reverse()`
6. foreach(array):
   compare the reversed string with each element of array.
7. Bingo! return the index

```
inputsting = 'sheep';
reversestring = inputsting.split("").reverse().join("");
string s = "['sheep', 'sheep', 'sheep', 'peehs', 'sheep']";
s = s.ltrim('[').rtrim(']');
string [] ss = s.split(',');
int i=0;
for(string s1 : ss)
{
    if (s1==reversestring)
        return i;
    else i++;
}
```

Comment: `String.reverse` is not a function

Comment: I mean "Inputstring.reverse()". I have assumed he is aware of string functions

Comment: @DeepakKumar That's what Rayon meant: it doesn't exist for string values.

Comment: there is a function to reverse a string using reverse() function

Comment: JavaScript does not use type declarations (multiple places). Your `string s` line is assigning an [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) to what you're intending to be a [`String`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String). Multiple other issues. As other's have said, `String` does not have a `.reverse()` method in it's prototype.

Comment: Basically, you appear to have written this for a language other than JavaScript. While it's not forbidden to use a language not specified by the question OP, it usually isn't received well, particularly when you don't say what language you're using.

Comment: I am sorry, I am new to this platform didn't checked the language. I have edited my answer for java script.BTW thank you for the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

you can check on the below way.

I hope the below code will solve the issue.

```js
const isReverseString = (str,orgStr) =>
Array.from(str).reverse().join("") === orgStr ? true : false


let arrOfString =  ['sheep', 'sheep', 'sheep', 'peehs', 'sheep'] ;
const orgStr = "sheep";

const findIndexOfArrofString = (arr) => {
  arr.forEach((item,index) => isReverseString(item, orgStr) ? console.log("index is:",index) : null)
}


console.log(findIndexOfArrofString(arrOfString))
```